# Python: VTK Distance from points to vtkLineSource

Tags: python, numpy, math, scipy, vtk

I have the following problem. I create Tubes around vtkLineSource. Now i want to calculate the shortest distance of points or  one point(point1) to the original line created by the different points. Is it possible to do that?

```
import vtk
point1=[10,10,10]
arr=[[1,2,3],[2,4,6],[4,8,12]]
linePoints = vtk.vtkPoints()
for i in arr:
    linePoints.InsertNextPoint(i)

line = vtk.vtkLineSource()
line.SetPoints(linePoints)
line.Update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know all the line segments (`arr[0]-arr[1], arr[1]-arr[2]` etc.), so you can compute the distance to each of them (there is a static method for it in [vtkLine](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkLine.html#a3da29308d6f73f4cf5aca64ebeedd8c9)) and look which of those is the shortest.

Comment: Is there a numpy way to compute all the distances to the line segment pairs with the vtkLine function?

Comment: I am not familiar with numpy so I don't know.